# How to forcibly free physical memory when `clear` doesn't work?

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

**Differences from proposed duplicate:**

First of all, I'd like to say that I'm not talking about freeing the physical memory intended to a variable so in this case the commands `clear`, `close` or `pack` don't work. In my case, the physical memory of my computer runs out despite using them after running my MATLAB script (not too long) a few times.

I'm using MATLAB R2016b in a windows computer with 8Gb RAM. As I said  before, after several times, the physical memory of my computer starts to run out so the only way to keep running the code is restarting the program (I can't do this all time when I want to run the script).

```
clear all
clc
close all
%Datos entrada:
Long=60;                                  %Longitud viga (m)
p_uni=1;                                   %Carga repartida uniforme(kN/m)
n_division = 1000;                           %Numero divisiones de la viga
H = 3;                                    %Componente horizontal en extremos
lon_barra=Long/n_division;
a = Long;
P_y = p_uni*lon_barra;

% Inicio programa:

if rem(n_division-1,2)==0   %Para el caso de numero par de fuerzas, que hace que el foco fin-comienzo de la representacion de fuerzas
    y_force(1:((n_division-1)/2))=(((n_division-1)/2):-1:1)*P_y;
    y_force(((n_division-1)/2)+1:n_division-1)=(1:1:(n_division-1)/2)*P_y;
else                        %Para el caso de numero impar de fuerzas,
    y_force(n_division)=P_y/2;
    y_force(1:n_division/2)=((n_division/2-0.5):-1:0.5)*P_y;
    y_force(n_division/2+1:n_division)=(0.5:1:n_division/2)*P_y;
end
%Numero par de fuerzas sobre nodos internos
if rem(n_division-1,2)==0       
    N = ones(1,n_division-1);
    alfa = ones(1,n_division-1);
    for i=1:n_division-1
        alfa(i) = atan(y_force(i)/H);
        N(i) = y_force(i)/sin(alfa(i));
    end
    alfa_fin = zeros(1,n_division);
    alfa_fin(1:length(alfa)/2)=alfa(1:length(alfa)/2);
    alfa_fin(length(alfa)/2+2:end)=alfa(length(alfa)/2+1:end);

    N_fin = ones(1,n_division);  
    N_fin(1:length(N)/2)=N(1:length(N)/2);
    N_fin(length(N)/2+2:end)=N(length(N)/2+1:end);
    N_fin(length(N)/2+1) = H;

    for i=1:n_division+1
        if i<=((n_division+1)/2)
            if i==1;
                y(i) = 0;
            else
                y(i) = tan(alfa_fin(i-1))*lon_barra+y(i-1);
            end
        else
            y(i)=y(i-1)-tan(alfa_fin(i-1))*lon_barra;
        end
    end  
%Numero impar de fuerzas sobre nodos internos
else                   
    N = ones(1,n_division);
    alfa = ones(1,n_division);
    for i=1:n_division
        alfa(i) = atan(y_force(i)/H);
        N(i) = y_force(i)/sin(alfa(i));
    end
    y = ones(1,n_division+1);
    for i=1:n_division+1
        if i<=((n_division/2)+1)
            if i==1;
                y(i) = 0;
            else
                y(i) = tan(alfa(i-1))*lon_barra+y(i-1);
            end
        else
            y(i)=y(i-1)-tan(alfa(i-1))*lon_barra;
        end
    end
end
%Densidad para altura objetivo:
q_final=H/lon_barra;
```

This image shows the increases of memory required after the code is run each time:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the relevant parts of your code - otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions. If you disagree with your previous question being marked as a duplicate, edit the original question and explain how it is different. You were even advised in the comments to do this, and you've ignored it. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will get better tips than those appear in the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html) on this subject. One specific point I'd like to point out is this:

> ***Long-Term Usage (Windows Systems Only)***
>
> *On 32-bit Microsoft® Windows®, the workspace of MATLAB can fragment over time due to the fact that the Windows memory manager does not return blocks of certain types and sizes to the operating system. Clearing the MATLAB workspace does not fix this problem. You can minimize the problem by allocating the largest variables first. This cannot address, however, the eventual fragmentation of the workspace that occurs from continual use of MATLAB over many days and weeks, for example. The only solution to this is to save your work and restart MATLAB.*
>
> *The `pack` command, which saves all variables to disk and loads them back, does not help with this situation.*

I know it says "32-bit", but I bet this also applies in some degree to 64-bit systems.

Bottom line - you need to follow the guidelines of the documentation, paying special attention to **preallocation** (you grow `y` inside a loop).

Another thing you can do is profile memory usage to find some memory leaks.

Yet another option, which is available to you on R2016b, is using [`tall` arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html) - which are not being kept in RAM.